# License for MySQL connector

Tags: mysql, licensing, lazarus, connector

I would like to know if I can use [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) (libmysql.dll) with comercial Lazarus project. As far as I know, it's under GNU GPL.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licencing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if you want to sell your end product, unless you want to licence it under GPL as well.
MySQL Connector also provides commercial licenses for that purpose.

Comment: Doesn't GNU GPL means i have to make it open-source? Another question: MySQL connector is DLL (dynamic library) so am I able to use it if it would be under LGPL?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to use it under LGPL.

Comment: Not all DLLs are automatically LGPL. DLLs under GPL are certainly possible, and afaik this is the case with MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right on the page you're linking to:

> MySQL open source software is provided under the [GPL License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/oem/ which should tell you which is the license you need.